# How to efficiently append items to large arrays in Swift?

Tags: arrays, swift, dynamic-arrays

I am working on a Swift project the involves very large dynamically changing arrays.  I am running into a problem where each successive operation take longer than the former.  I am reasonably sure this problem is caused by appending to the arrays, as I get the same problem with a simple test that just appends to a large array.

My Test Code:

```
import Foundation

func measureExecution(elements: Int, appendedValue: Int) -> Void {
    var array = Array(0...elements)
    //array.reserveCapacity(elements)
    
    let start = DispatchTime.now()
    array.append(appendedValue)
    let end = DispatchTime.now()
    print(Double(end.uptimeNanoseconds - start.uptimeNanoseconds) / 1_000_000_000)
}

for i in 0...100 {
    measureExecution(elements: i*10000, appendedValue: 1)
}
```

This tries for a 100 different array sizes between 10000 and 1000000, timing how long it take to append one item to the end of the array.  As I understand it, Swift arrays are dynamic arrays that will reallocate memory geometrically (it allocates more and more memory each time it needs to reallocate), which Apple's documentation says should mean `appending a single element to an array is an O(1) operation when averaged over many calls to the append(_:) method` ([source](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/array/3126937-append)).  As such, I don't think memory allocation is causing the issue.

However, there is a linear relationship between the length of the array and the time it takes to append an element.  I graphed the times for a bunch of array lengths, and baring some outliers it is pretty clearly O(n).  I also ran the same test with reserved capacity (commented out in the code block) to confirm that memory allocation was not the issue, and I got nearly identical results:
[image: Graph of array length and append time]

How do I efficiently append to the end of massive arrays (preferably without using `reserveCapacity`)?

Comment: Take a look at `Deque` from the [Swift Collections Package](https://swift.org/blog/swift-collections/), it may be suitable for your case.

Comment: I can't reproduce your results. What hardware are you running this on? I'm testing on a MBP, and just running this, unoptimized, as a commandline app in Xcode. I find the append time to be flat, ranging from 7x10^-7 to 8x10^-6.

Comment: I will look into Deque; That looks promising.  As for the platform, I have tried in an Xcode playground, Swift Playgrounds on Mac and iPad, and just for my sanity, I checked on Replit.com, they gave me the same results.  The values were different across platforms but generally worked their way up from thousandths of a second to tenths of a second, as the array size increased.  If your computer is on the faster side, you might want to increase the number of loop iterations or the constant that i is multiplied by as the effect shows up relatively slowly.

Comment: What's the x axis? The base size of the array (multiplied by 10,000)?

Comment: Yes.  Each unit on the x-axis is one pass through the `for i in 0...100`... loop, so it will have an array 10,000 indices longer than the last.

Comment: @Alladinian I have tried Deque.  It doesn’t seem to markedly improve the performance.  Re-reading the press release on swift.org, I think Deque makes it so that adding a value onto the beginning of the array is as efficient as appending to the end but doesn’t speed up appending to the end (I am new to packages, so I might have used Deque incorrectly, but I believe this to be the case).

Answer (score 0):

From what I've read, Swift arrays pre-allocate storage. Each time you fill an Array's allocated storage, it doubles the space allocated. That way you don't do a new memory allocation that often, and also don't allocate a bunch of space you don't need.

The Array class does have a `reserveCapacity(_:)`. If you know how many elements you are going to store you might want to try that.

Comment: I think OP knows about `reserveCapacity`, they used it in their code and chart